# bundle : The term 'bundle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, bundle, github-pages

it is my first question in STACK!
I'm trying to create Github pages account using https://startbootstrap.com/theme/clean-blog-jekyll.

In the terminal i'm getting following error message:

```
> bundle : The term 'bundle' is not recognized as the name of a  cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the  spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the  path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1
> + bundle exec jekyll serve
> + ~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bundle:String) [], 
>     CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've tried bundle install but not worked.

Comment: You have to install bundler for ruby from the looks of it. Have a look at [bundler.io](https://bundler.io/).

Comment: @Henry thanks man, I've just learned how to use powershell

Answer (score 0):

I've installed bundler using **powershell** instead of VS code terminal.
For documentation :

*bundler.io*